# How can I check the first character of a scanned string even if it is empty?

Tags: string, go, user-input

I want to have the user be able to put in input and check to see if the first character is an `a` but if they leave the string empty then it will cause the following error:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0
```

My code looks like:

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
        var a string;
        fmt.Scanln(&a);
        if string(a[0]) == "a" {
                fmt.Println("if true");
        } 
}
```

Comment: Check the string's length first.

Comment: `startsWithA := strings.HasPrefix(a, “a”)`

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it, will only check if the first character is `"a"`

```
var a string;
fmt.Scanln(&a);
if len(a) > 0 && string(a[0]) == "a" {
    fmt.Println("if true")
}
```

Another, will work with leading spaces, for example when the input to `Scanln` is `"     a"`:

```
var a string;
fmt.Scanln(&a);
if strings.HasPrefix(a, "a") {
    fmt.Println("if true")
}
```